# Passing arguments to code behind c#

Tags: c#, webforms

We have looked and looked all over the internet but we were unable to find a solution.
We have a linkbutton and we want to pass a parameter to the code behind.
This is the code:

```
<% foreach (Academia.CourseEN curso in MyCourses) { %>
            <% string id = curso.Id.ToString(); %>
       <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-lg-3">
          <div class="panel panel-warning">
            <div class="panel-heading"><%: curso.Title %></div>
            <div class="panel-body"><%: curso.Id %></div>
            <div class="panel-body"><%: curso.Description %></div>
            <div class="panel-body"><%: curso.Price %></div>
            <div class="panel-body"><%: curso.Category %></div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">

                <asp:LinkButton ID="ENameLinkBtn" runat="server" Text="Button" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("id") %>' OnClick="DeleteCourse_Click" ></asp:LinkButton>

                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
       <%} %>
```

The problem is that eval always returns an empty value, which is not the case as when we display the id it has a value.
I post the code behind code as well:

```
LinkButton btn = (LinkButton)(sender);
string yourValue = btn.CommandArgument;
ErrorMessage.Text = yourValue;
```

I dont know what else to do or what else to try, anything would behighly appreciated.
Thanks everyone.

Comment: Did you try providing a CommandName with the argument?

Comment: @S.Brentson yes, the same thing happens

Comment: And if you put a static value instead of the eval() expression?

Comment: In ASP.NET WebForms, you should avoid using an explicit `foreach` loop to render multiple instances of a server control, like `<asp:LinkButton>`. Instead, you should use a data-binding control like `<asp:Repeater>` or `<asp:ListView>`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a javascript function `DeleteCourse()`

```
function DeleteCourse()
{
   var param = $("#ENameLinkBtn").val();
   $.ajax(
         url:"your web method",
         data: '"param":"' + param + '"'
         ....)
}
```

Then assign it to your button `OnClick="DeleteCourse()"`

Comment: It is a school work and they dont let us use javascript, but thanks anyway @jgauffin